# preg replace for whitespace to be used in html format

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I am trying to replace a certain word in php and include a whitespace in it.

This string will eventually be encode as html format. However, after encoding in html format, &nbsp always turns up to be a 'newline' instead of 'one standard space'. May i know why is that so? Thanks

```
$storeAddr = preg_replace('/test/', "<br>&nbsp;test1", $storeAddr); 

I.E
    string: 1)xxxxtestxxxx
    current output: 1)xxx

                    testxxxx

    desired output: 1)xxx
                      testxxxx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what [`<br>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) is doing?

It inserts line break. So in your code `<br>` turns up to be a 'newline'.

Comment: yea i know.. so including my <br> & &nbsp...i end up having two new line instead of one newline and one blank space infront of "test1"

Comment: @Jonathan, is preg_replace the only function that you use for strings formatting? Don't you use anything like nl2br?

Comment: only using preg_replace ... using it to replace certain word and in additional adding a space infront of the word for formatting purposes. n12br does not help me in this situation..

Comment: So, @Jonathan, after performing all manipulations on your string you should get such string: `1)xxxx<br>&nbsp;test1xxxx`. In [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/dR95u/) it works as expected.

Comment: yeah thats why i am also trying to find out why.. anyway thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i made a mistake somewhere along the way... found the mistake after doing a line by line check :)